# How to use SSL certificates for Kubernetes Pods with the client role, not server role

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

I have an application running in Kubernetes Pods. It needs to make https calls to some external service. And this external service asks for SSL certificate.   I understand if w/o Kubernetes, the certs can be downloaded somewhere on a Linux machine, applications on the machine refer to that certs by path. But how to install certs for Kubernetes cluster? What's the best practise?

Here are some info that I've collected by searching online, correct me if I'm wrong. But just couldn't find answers to my question.

1. lots of guide/blogs/docmentation are talking about signing
   certificates to other clients when provide services from Kubernetes,
   but for my case, it's the other way around --- call external
   services with ssl certificates from Kubernetes.
2. I thought of installing ssl certificate up-front in cluster
   machines. but

   1) can the installation be automatically done in a
   secured way?

   2) looks like pods sharing files from host machine is
   anti-parttern and may not even supported by Kubernetes, especially
   in Google Kubernetes Engine(we use GKE) .

So... any insights or suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is not about Kubernetes, but rather how to add certificates to the way you're packaging your container images (likely with Docker).

You can easily install CA certificates to your container images by running the following commands:

- If you're using a debian/ubuntu-based image:

  ```
  apt-get install -qqy ca-certificates
  ```
- If you're on alpine-based images:

  ```
  apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
  ```

These will make sure your container has the up-to-date root CA certificates that are used to verify validity of TLS certificates presented  by public websites/services.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can do it  , choose **any one only** based on your convenience :

1.via Only **few lines of Code Change in Application** - `this leads burden on developer`.

2.via Only **few additional lines in Dockerfile while building container** image - `this set responsibility on either developer or devops based on who owns dockercontainer creation.`

3. **Best way** - via Only **Kubernetes Deployment yaml**/Helm chart changes while deploying Pod by putting cert in config map mapped to CA root location of pod. `-this is one time activity put entire responsibility on dev ops and will automatically apply on all future apps.`

detailed steps on each of this with pro and cons and example is here :

https://medium.com/@paraspatidar/add-self-signed-or-ca-root-certificate-in-kubernetes-pod-ca-root-certificate-store-cb7863cb3f87

Comment: I know this post is a bit old.  I have added my certificates in confg map.  Then add volume mounts and volume to add the cert to my pod.  After the deployment I verified certificates have been copied to /etc/ssl/certs folder.  But my java program can't find it.  It raises ```unable to find valid certification path to requested target```.  Any idea why java does not use the certs from /etc/ssl/certs?

My configuration
volumeMounts:
  - name: ca-intermediate-pemstore
    mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/ca_intermediate_base64.cer
    subPath: ca_intermediate_base64.cer
    readOnly: true

Comment: 1. Hope that it has been mouted with subpath option so that it doesnt wipe out existing certs?    2. for java  , you might also need to consider adding them at  java installation's version specific  certificate location, as in some scenario we have seen that adding to default CA trust manager also doesnt help and installing them in java's standard installed version's certificate location , it works fine for java based applications.